# stack pop() causes "reference binding to misaligned address" error

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stack

I'm trying to code a solution for this leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-frequency-stack/

```
class FreqStack {
public:
    
   
    map<int, int>mp;
    map<int, stack<int>, greater<int>>st;
    FreqStack() {
        
    }
    
    void push(int x) {
        mp[x]++;
        st[mp[x]].push(x);
        
       
    }
    
    int pop() {
        stack<int>&v=st.begin()->second;
        
        int t=v.top();
        
        
        if(!v.empty()){
        v.pop();
        }
        else{
            st.erase(st.begin());
        }
       
        return t;
    }
};
```

why does

```
v.pop()
```

cause "reference binding to misaligned address" error?

Comment: This doesn't seem related, but you're checking for the stack being empty after already assuming it isn't.

Comment: ya i know i was just trying different things to see if i could make the error go away

Comment: What does the calling code do? I get nothing from address sanitizer with `.push(0)` then `.pop()` nor `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`.

Comment: Fear [shotgun debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging). Not only does it often make things worse, it makes it harder confirm exactly what you did to fix the problem if the problem does go away. If you don't know what the fix was and why it worked, you may have only hidden the problem and moved where it manifests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the reference as in the above answer - you need the reference to actually make changes to st. If you dont declare v as a reference, you end up making changes only locally to v, and not to st.

using the example from leetcode, after all the pushes, `st[3]` should have a stack containing `[5]`. In the first pop, that stack is not empty, so we pop it. So `st[3]` should be an empty stack. Then in the next pop, `v = st.begin() -> second` will return this empty stack, so pop / top fails. Thats why commenting the pop line or making v not a reference works in terms of fixing the problem, but doesnt actually do anything functionality wise.

What you need to do is: after popping, if it is an empty stack you need to delete/erase that frequency and stack from st. So your pop code will look something like this

```
    stack<int>&v=st.begin()->second;
    
    int t=v.top();
    
    
    if(!v.empty()){
    v.pop();
    }

    if (v.empty()) {
        st.erase(st.begin());
    }
   
    return t;
```

only change i have made is turn the else into an if. I would prefer to have the `t = v.top()` inside the v is not empty case, but since we are deleting the frequency when the stack is empty, we should be covered (v should never be empty). That should fix your problem - but it is not the correct answer to the leetcode question. Ill leave you to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's a problem here `stack<int>&v=st.begin()->second;`, maybe try to implement your algorithm without using a reference there.

Technically I guess you're referencing your pointer to part of a memory, which does not yet exist, and you're getting a UB, as you'd continue to read the error.

If you'd remove `&`, you'd see that your code has no bug. However, it'd output partially incorrect results.

---

Apart from that, we can also use `unordered_map`.

This'll get through:

```
// This block might trivially optimize the exec time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}();


// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>

static const struct FreqStack {
    using SizeType = std::uint_fast32_t;
    FreqStack() {}
    std::unordered_map<SizeType, SizeType> frequencies;
    std::unordered_map<SizeType, std::stack<SizeType>> mapstack;
    SizeType max_fr = 0;

    const void push(const int x) {
        max_fr = std::max(max_fr, ++frequencies[x]);
        mapstack[frequencies[x]].push(x);
    }


    const int pop() {
        const auto top = mapstack[max_fr].top();
        mapstack[max_fr].pop();

        if (mapstack[frequencies[top]--].empty()) {
            --max_fr;
        }

        return top;
    }

};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-frequency-stack/) which you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions in there, with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including efficient algorithms and asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: "Probably there's a problem here" isn't very reassuring in an answer. That line of code is a red flag, sure, but that's insufficient for explaining the error.

Comment: I can't. That line was a red flag, but I didn't see anything actually incorrect.